# Shorten SQLite Function

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am fairly new to python and I was wondering if I could shorten some repetitive code like the function below. I am making a program that uses sqlite3 to log a users personal (running) records and info about them. The program can then display them, order them, etc.. The code below is for my delete function. Thanks for the help!

```
def delete_pr(conn, c, command):
if (len(command) == 1):
    print("Delete what???")
if (len(command) == 2): 
    c.execute("DELETE FROM personal_records WHERE (event = ?)", (command[1], ))
    conn.commit()
if (len(command) == 3):
    c.execute("DELETE FROM personal_records WHERE (event = ?) AND (time = ?)", (command[1], command[2]))
    conn.commit()
if(len(command) == 4):
    c.execute("DELETE FROM personal_records WHERE (event = ?) AND (time = ?) AND (date = ?)", (command[1], command[2], command[3], ))
    conn.commit()
if(len(command) == 5):
    c.execute("DELETE FROM personal_records WHERE (event = ?) AND (time = ?) AND (date = ?) AND (info = ?)", (command[1], command[2], command[3], command[4], ))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure; you could improve on how `cmd` is built (which I'll leave as an exercise).

```
def delete_pr(conn, c, command):
    if (len(command) == 1):
        print("Delete what???")
    elif len(command)<=5:
        # Build the query out of enough parts to match the length of command
        cmd = "".join(["DELETE FROM personal_records WHERE (event = ?)"," AND (time = ?)"," AND (date = ?)"," AND (info = ?)"][:len(command)])
        # Execute it using all but the first element of command
        c.execute( cmd, tuple(command[1:]) )
        conn.commit()
```